# Can I restart X without having to close all applications in my current session?

Tags: xorg

I found when I want to change input method, I should restart X. But I don't want to close all applications. How to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't.

What you can do is start a new X-session on a different tty (screen) which should leave the apps running in the first session untouched. (This is how some display managers [e.g., KDM] allow multiple log-ins of different users using the the same physical display/keyboard.)

Source: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/how-to-restart-x-without-having-to-close-connected-applications-689430/

Comment: Could you give the command to do that in this answer? Would be nice not to have to google :)

Answer (score 2):

The apps started over X will be killed if you restart X. You cannot avoid that.

Comment: Does anyone know what signal these apps receive when X is terminated? And does it depend on what signal terminates X? I can imagine reasons for the system to be designed so they receive SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGKILL (or some combination of these, separated by a time interval during which the app can do its own cleanup).

Comment: Eliah: it's not a really a signal: the socket that the X clients (your apps) are communicating with Xorg over is closed. This may cause the client to receive a SIGPIPE on the next write to the socket, or that the write fails. It's certainly possible that applications can perform cleanup here.

Comment: Would it be possible to run some kind of proxy in front of Xorg socket to allow redirecting socket traffic to newly restarted X?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen if you manage to get it to work, *xmove* does exactly this. The problem is, it hasn't been maintained for 14 years. This could probably also be done with *Xpra*, which is still maintained, but its main purpose is quite different, so it would require fiddling.